# SignalR asynchronous task

Tags: signalr-hub, signalr-2

In my SignalR2 hub I added an async method StartMyTask() that will get called from the client, as well as OnConnected() method. However whenever OnConnected executes it never connects to the hub (or return base.OnConnected()) never gets hit:

Hub:

```
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        StartMyTask().Wait(); // add stuff to db here
        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    static async Task StartMyTask()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
             Thread.Sleep(10);
        });
    }
```

1. Why am I not able to connect? When I make StartMyTask not a task it works.
2. I assume that if I did not want to wait until DB write I would remove Wait() - Correct? Would this cause any issues if the connection happened and DB wrote after?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there is a current `SynchronizationContext` that only allows a single thread in at a time (e.g., an ASP.NET synchronization context). I explain the [deadlock semantics](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) in full on my blog.

SignalR isn't supposed to leak `SynchronizationContext.Current` - I was under the impression that they fixed this, but apparently not.

Regardless, you can fix your code by not blocking on asynchronous work:

```
public override async Task OnConnected()
{
  await StartMyTask();
  await base.OnConnected();
}
```

Comment: await doesn't work, as I'm calling this from OnConnected (Not async method). StartMyTask() - without Wait() keyword works, but do you forsee any issues with saving stuff to DB after OnConnected exited?- I mean this works...so what if I'm already connected and my info got saved a little later

Comment: also, is StartMyTask() same as having Task t = StartMyTask()?

Comment: @BobSwanson: Just make it `async` as I did in my answer, and then `await` will work.